# Adjust row height on CSS Grid to the smallest cell

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a CSS grid of one row and two columns. I want the row height to be limited by the first column so that, if the one on the right is higher its overflow is hidden and then the user has to scroll. Is that possible?

Comment: You should add some code showing what you have tried so we can help debug